# How to extract UID from my NFC tag with iPhone application and reuse it in the code for DB query

Tags: web-applications, nfc, rfid, uid, core-nfc

For my project, I would like to do an NFC tag based build taxonomy. I would like to scan the NFC tag with the built-in iPhone/Android application (not an app store app) to open the URL stored on the NFC tag in the browser.
So far so good. This is
Now I need the UID of an NFC tag to be able to call the corresponding information in my database (PostgreSQL). The information should be displayed in the web app.

The Question:
How do I get the UID parallel to the URL from the NFC tag into my program to start the database query?

Thanks a lot for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are storing the URL in Ndef format on the Tag and relying of the system to launch the URL?

There are some options:-

1. Write your own app to read the URL and UID and then launch a browser with the URL and UID as parameters
2. Use a NFC Tag that has special features that allow dynamic data. e.g. The Ntag 21x series of Tags allow the UID to be mirrored in to the data section and thus can generate a NDef URL that contains the UID as a parameter and then the system apps will launch the right URL.
3. This only works on Android and only with Chrome - The Tag launches the URL and the web page uses Web NFC for the web page to read the Tag UID.

Answer (score 0):

In addition Andrew's suggestions you may add the UID to the URL as a parameter. This means that when you program the tags, you have to read the UID first, combine that into the URL and store that in the tag.

Comment: Yes I forgot this one as an option and as UID's are not guaranteed to be Unique in NFC then you might as well forgot using the Tag's UID and just write your own Unique Identifier in to the URL when you program each Tag.